# Node architecture: Is libuv's event loop exposed to V8?

Tags: node.js, v8, libuv

At the end of [this article](https://medium.com/@ghaiklor/how-nodejs-works-bfe09efc80ca#.tvs22y5oy) *(section EventLoop)* it says that libuv's event loop is passed to V8. On the first reading that seemed to make sence: In the browser V8 has it's own event loop, in Node it gets that of libuv. But then I started digging into the code and couldn't find a proof where the loop is passed to V8.

[StartNodeInstance](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src%2Fnode.cc#L4276) leads after some steps to the creation of a new [Environment](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src%2Fenv-inl.h#L215) instance. The constructor is passed a newly created [V8 Context](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started#null), which is created from a V8 isolate, as well as a pointer to the libuv default loop.

Then the loop is passed to the creation of a [IsolateData](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src%2Fenv-inl.h#L48) instance. I couldn't find a hint that the loop is actually passed or registered to V8. Nor that the `Environment::New` belongs to the V8 namespace, as claimed at the end of the article from above.

> An isolate is a V8 VM instance with its own heap. A context is an
>   execution environment that allows separate, unrelated, JavaScript code
>   to run in a single instance of V8. You must explicitly specify the
>   context in which you want any JavaScript code to be run.

Comment: I got some answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libuv/s_bhlOhegzY

Comment: [JavaScript & Node.Js architecture](http://games.fkmt.de/docu#x1-630005.1.3.1)